# How many tiers do you need?

Tags: java, mysql, n-tier-architecture

We have a web-app that consists of web-tier (PHP), app-tier (Java) and DB (mysql).
web-tier communicates with app-tier AND with DB to retrieve some data.
One of our clients insists on separating each tier with a firewall and blocking traffic from web-tier to DB. They claim that this is insecure and app-tier needs to have the "get data" function that will be used by web-tier instead of reading data directly from DB.

It seems like a real waste to tunnel data through app-tier when it can be easily accessed by web-tier directly from DB. Read-only data can come from highly-optimized views and can be presented as-is. This greatly simplifies the design and removes additional problems like paging. 
The technique is known as Fast-Lane-Reader and advocates retrieving tabular read-only data directly from DB. For updates the app-tier is used where business rules are applied.

So my question is whether this 3-tiered firewall-isolated topology can be adjusted and allow direct traffic from web to db tiers?

Thanks in advance,
Philopator.

Comment: Quick question: Are they paying by the hour?

Comment: In what way are they saying the app is "insecure" ? Are you the developer of the Java app too? If not, then it makes sense that they don't want you to have direct access to the database

Comment: @JohnFx: They are licensing the system from us - fixed installation cost, then monthly payments.

Comment: @Mark S: we are developers of the entire system. It's already working in number of deployments. Furthermore we're PCI certified (talking about security).

Comment: Ok, I think you need to provide more detail if you want to get any real help from us. Your client is concerned about firewalls being in place and only want one app / layer to touch the database. Why? Do they have a reason for this? What is there exact "security" concern? Is it just a hard policy they have? If so, then please add those details to the question so we can take on your customer's perspective in our answers. Have they told you how your design exposes them to some risk?

Comment: @Mark S: They don't specify why. They just say that they're uncomfortable with Flows from the WEB DMZ directly into the DB DMZ. And they ASK US why we're comfortable with that. 
I think they already have the infrastructure in place and they are trying to fit all apps into that infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure I buy the whole security angle, but I do think it is wise to limit/eliminate direct chatter between the presentation tier (web app) and the data tier (database) to clearly delineate the separation of concerns.

For one thing, it encourages code re-use and encapsulating business logic rather than spreading it out throughout the application. For example, if you ever had multiple front ends (desktop, web, mobile) the duplication of logic would be minimized.

Secondly, it helps to future proof your application somewhat. For example, if you went from PHP to ASP.NET or a Mobile OS front end it would minimize the work involved to the relevant parts to display the data.

All in all, it is probably a good idea anyway. If there are some benefits in terms of the security architecture. Bonus.

Comment: Tnx for the reply but i don't like to spend significant effort now for theoretical benefits tomorrow (mobile client, etc). High productivity environments like Ruby on Rails use DB directly with great success. 
The concerns are still separated by web-tier doing ONLY presentation. It's only a question about where the data is coming from. I don't see much additional value in the app-level tunneling.

Comment: @Philopator I think you're looking at it the wrong way around. Have you got any real, measurable reason to bypass the app layer? If not, don't. Don't try to future-proof your application against nonexistent performance bottlenecks.

Comment: The question is do i have any real, measurable reason to tunnel through app-level? The answer is NO. I'm not trying to future-proof against performance problems. I'm more concerned about wasting time on development and maintenance of the dummy-proxy code. 
We're not not planning on any mobile client so preparing for it now IS future-proofing.

Comment: @Philopator In the time you spent on proving that they'are wrong, you probably could've implemented the proxy layer. But it seems that you had made your mind up anyway and all you wanted was just confirmation that you were right.

Comment: @biziclop, actually i wanted to find any compelling reasons to spend extra time on the proxy. So far none of the mentioned reasons justify extra coding. I'm not saying that those are not valid reasons - only that they don't apply to our case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you explain to your client how you define "value" and let them explain to you how they define it. My guess is you are not on the same page. It sounds like you value [fast and cheep over quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle) (of design). Does your client agree with this approach? It sounds like they are more concerned with quality of design than fast and cheep. If this is the case, I'd listen to your client (since they are paying you, - and they should be willing to pay for that quality). Maybe after a conversation about defining value your customer will see it your way. Maybe not.

There are valid reasons - namely maintainability and extensibility - for keeping your PHP layer away from the DB layer (and only accessing data via the Java middle tier).

Just think of the maintainability reason:

A middle tier such as your Java layer acts as a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). The database schema can be changed (for whatever reason) at any time, and your PHP layer does not need to care about that (meaning you don't need to update anything in your PHP code). Only the Java layer needs to be updated. The Java layer maintains a consistent interface (for your PHP code to write against).

Now, if you change the DB schema while both the Java and PHP layers access it directly, BOTH layers will have to be updated. This is a brittle design (a maintenance nightmare), and especially bad if you are not in charge of both the Java application layer AND the PHP layer.

Comment: 1) The only client's concern is security - not quality vs. cheapness. I doubt that dummy proxy materially enhances security.

Comment: 2) There is a difference between logical layering of the code and isolating DB from UI and physical deployment of different tiers.
3) There are countless extremely successful LAMP-based app that never used middle-tier. Kayako, Magento come to mind.
4) Having dozens of read-only screens it seems like a real waste to manufacture DTOs for each.
5) Talking from experience, when any little thing changes in DB - those DTOs have to updated with DB and UI - THAT is nightmare.

Comment: I had problem submitting second part of my answer. (see points 2-5)
As for who controls the DB - it's our system that is licensed to them. Funny thing is that the system is already implemented and is working fine as it is. It's Operations department at client side that's making the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Philopator, I would say the point is not in having firewalls to block communication between FrontEnd (PHP) and DataLayer (MySql), even without any firewall it is usually not good to have a direct link UI -> Database.

In your case you even have a nice middle-tier done in Java, I would definitely tunnel everything through the java layer in order to fully decouple UI and Database.

Don't be afraid in performance issues normally there aren't any or could be addressed, and I do think you can do everything like accessing views or stored procedures, paging sorting an so on having your calls started from the java component instead of the php presentation layer.

Comment: Of course i can access stored procs, paging, etc. But doing this at the app level adds ZERO value. It's a dummy pass-through. What is the benefit in doing that? As for decoupling UI from DB, then if DB changes, then not only UI needs to be adjusted but also the app-level tunnel as well. So what do we gain by that?

Comment: As johnFX told you, you gain that you could reuse the middle layer from any user interface, imagine if you have an android Application, a windows client, a web client in php and a web client in ASP.NET... do you want to write table names, stored procedure names and everything needed to connect to the database in every single front end? if you isolate the lower level ( database ) and do not expose its details to the presentation layer, you can then change from mysql to sql server or oracle for example, with minimal and centralized changes.

Comment: IMHO this is over-engineering. We're not planning to have windows or mobile client, we're not planning to switch to another DB. The presentation logic is very straightforward. Anything additional IS future-proofing "just in case". This is why Ruby on Rails is so much more productive than traditional 3-tier J2EE.

Comment: @Philopator And obviously you're not planning for any data structure changes and caching either. Just rewrite it in Ruby on Rails then. You know better anyway.

Comment: @biziclop i AM planning on data structure changes and caching. but changing data structure will require modifying the proxy and Data Transfer Objects in addition to modifying the DB and UI. As for caching - it's most efficient to cache a completely rendered page using Varnish/Squid or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To give a real-world, "today-proofing" benefit of going through the app layer, think of it like encapsulation.  You should only have one way of setting/getting a particular piece of data, because you only want validation/formatting/filtering in one place.

Imagine you have a WidgetService.addWidget() service method in your java code.  You want to make sure all widgets are of types the current user is allowed to work with, so addWidget() checks the permissions for that.  Now if your PHP code tries to add a widget to the database directly, it bypasses those checks.

Comment: I totally understand it. That's why i wrote that UPDATES are done only by the app - that's where business/security rules are applied. But reading and paging read-only data can be done directly at the web-level. Think of the reports and other frequently used stats.

Comment: @Philopator: Even though you are only reading from PHP, your PHP code needs to be aware of the DB schema, and so does the Java code. This is brittle design (you have to update your data access code in multiple tiers if the database schema changes)